# I cannot do anything from the AWS.Request.send() callback

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the AWS S3 Javascript SDK and i am trying to do some operations as using external functions or append some HTML code in a HTML div etc. all these things from my callback send() but nothing happens i get errors whereas i don't have any problem when i'm making these stuffs outside that send().

I have absolutely to write some specific code involving external functions inside  this send() that just can't be made outside . How to resolve this issue ?

You can have a glance on the AWS.request.send() [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#send-property)

Comment: Any chance you could add code snippets and error log samples?

Comment: When i'm calling the S3 getObject() function, the console log display a GET message error including the link of the file i want to get and finally a litte 403 Forbidden. I don't know why since i set all the authorization for everyone and unclocked read and write etc.